# Converting/filtering/deinterlacing VHS captures on Linux

Tags: video-capture, filter, linux, vhs, kdenlive

I'm pretty much a novice video editor especially on Linux. I'm looking to take a bunch of old home videos I captured using ffmpeg and clean them up as painlessly/automatically as possible. At this point I'm just more confused than anything else as to what to use. I have Ubuntu Studio 20.04 on an older gaming desktop and have messed around a bit with Kdenlive and Openshot, but have been disappointed trying to remove noise and deinterlace.

Any advice is appreciated, I'm not committed to open source, I could switch to Windows 10 if that's a better idea.

Thanks!

Comment: @Prof.Falken They have already captured the VHS.

Comment: I'm no expert in FFmpeg but I would have thought it would be able to do quite a bit of those transformations, I'm guessing using the same libraries that even programs like Adobe Premiere use - I know for sure that FFmpeg can use YADIF to deinterlace.

Comment: I use VirtualDub, or AviSynth+ if I feel patient. AviSynth and its Python clone work on Linux. Virtualdub works in Wine on Linux.

Comment: Thanks to both of you, I think the problem I'm having is most of the tools are so old that Google gives info from 10 years ago right along with current information. I've been playing with ffmpeg and have gotten deinterlacing down, virtualdub is so old, I guess I assumed it was not worth playing with, although I know it was rock solid. Maybe I'll get Wine going. Thanks again!